# Format currency in JavaScript removing .00

Tags: javascript, string, format, currency-formatting

I am currently formatting numbers to display as currency values using the following code:

```
return symbol + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
```

where symbol is £,$ etc. and value is a number with many decimal places. This works great but I now want to remove trailing `.00` if present.

Currently I have this output:

```
1.23454 => £1.23
1 => £1.00
50.00001 => £50.00
2.5 => £2.50
```

I would like the following:

```
1.23454 => £1.23
1 => £1
50.00001 => £50
2.5 => £2.50
```

Is there a cleaner way than:

```
var amount = symbol + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
return amount.replace(".00", "");
```

or is that solution the best way?

Comment: What are your criteria for "best"?

Comment: If the value is fractional I want to display the cents/pennies, its only when the cents/pennies are 0 that I want to remove the trailing zeros. I'll update the question with some more examples

Comment: Seems to me that `symbol + value.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00/g,'')` should do.

Comment: @RobG that works great thanks.

Comment: FYI, `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` be some help to you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [**Intl.NumberFormat**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). It is a very handy native api.

```js
let number = 1.23454;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'GBP'
}).format(number).replace(/(\.|,)00$/g, ''));
// → £1.23
```

Comment: but will it works for EUR?

Answer (score 3):

You can get [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) to round the currency to the nearest dollar (or pound or whatever) by setting `maximumSignificantDigits` to the number of digits in the integer part of your number

```js
let number = 999.50;

console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
  maximumSignificantDigits: Math.trunc(Math.abs(number)).toFixed().length,
}).format(number));  // $1,000 (rounds up because 50 cents)
```

If you're using negative currencies, keep in mind that `Intl.NumberFormat` has the more sensible behavior of [rounding away from zero](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866369) as opposed to other JavaScript methods like `Math.round`. For example, `Math.round(999.5)` returns `1000` but `Math.round(-999.5)` returns `-999` whereas using `Intl.NumberFormat` will return `1000` and `-1000`.

Comment: You're on the right track, but you used maximumSignificantDigits with some overly complex logic rather than using maximumFractionDigits.

Comment: @TimothyGonzalez you could’ve just edited my answer to make it better

Answer (score 1):

The native JS below will remove all trailing 0's from any number formatted as a string. NumberFormat automatically removes trailing zero's. I've chosen 20 as the maximumFractionDigits, because 20 is the max limit allowed so as long as you aren't dealing with more than 20 decimal places this will work for you in any use case.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 20
}).format('20.01230000') // 20.0123
```

Now if you are dealing with currency in Euro's meant to be viewed by a person here's what you really want.

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'GBP' ,
    minimumFractionDigits: 0,
    minimumFractionDigits: 20
}).format('20.01530000')) // 20.02
```

NumberFormat doesn't just trim it rounds as well which would only make sense to do so the loss in precision leads to the least loss of accuracy possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = 1.23454;
var symbol = '£';
value = value.toFixed(2);
var amount = symbol + value.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
alert(amount.replace(".00", ""));
```

Please change the value to test

Comment: This doesn't work for all locales, some languages [use a comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Hindu-Arabic_numerals).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @RobG, I can use:

```
symbol + value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").replace(/\.00/g, '')
```

Comment: This doesn't work for all locales, some languages [use a comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Hindu-Arabic_numerals).

Answer (score 0):

it can be done in a straightforward way

```
(parseFloat(percentage) / 100) * product.price)
    .toFixed(2)
    .toString()
    .replace('.00', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove trailing zeros in [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/intl/numberformat) function I used this code:

```
let number = 50;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
 style: 'currency',
 currency: 'USD',
 maximumSignificantDigits: (number + '').replace('.', '').length,
}).format(number)); // $50
```

Comment: This fails for numbers like 10.5... it will display '10.5', not '10.50'